# How to determine if app shows the "App X would like to use your current location" alert?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-location, cllocationmanager

Is there a way to figure out programmatically if CoreLocation is displaying that alert?

I'm displaying a welcome screen and want to adapt it's look if the alert shows up.

Comment: Isn't that a system alert? I think that's private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call the instance method of `CLLocationManager` `-startUpdatingLocation`, you can schedule a `NSTimer` with interval of 1 second for example and inside the timer callback call the `-authorizationStatus` *class* method of `CLLocationManager`. If it returns `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined`, then the alert is shown and the user should choose either to allow or deny. If he denies then the `-locationManager:didFailWithError` delegate method is called with error code `kCLErrorDenied` and you should stop updating location.